# Are decidability problems an example of strong emergence?

Tags: metaphysics, emergence

According to David Chalmers, speaking on Strong Emergence:

> We can say that a high-level phenomenon is strongly emergent with respect to a
>   low-level domain when the high-level phenomenon arises from the low-level domain, but truths concerning that phenomenon are not deducible even in principle from truths in the low-level domain.

He claims that the only "likely" example of strong emergence is that of consciousness. I would argue that there are plenty of other strongly emergent constructions in mathematics and logic. For instance, what about undecidable constructions, such as the Halting Problem and its applications?

For instance, Chaitin's constant fulfills all the requirements of strong emergence. It exists, and its existence is contingent on only a few low level parts. However, there is no algorithm that can determine or even approximate it in finite time. Would Chaitin's constant be an example of strong emergence?

Comment: According to Chalmers' notion of strong emergence, the existence of a high-level phenomenon, such as a subjective experience, would not be derivable from the low-level (physical) processes of the brain.  However, we can prove the existence of Chaitin's constant(s) and that there are uncountably many noncomputable real numbers. Similarly, we can derive at least one truth about provably undecidable statements, (e.g., the Continuum Hypothesis) - namely, that it is undecidable.

Comment: It depends what "deducible" means--Chalmers doesn't specify it has to be *algorithmically* deducible. If you had the right type of [oracle machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine) you could determine a unique value for every digit of Chaitin's constant from facts about Turing machine programs. In a possible worlds framework, there aren't any poss. worlds where the facts about the Turing machine programs are the same but Chaitin's constant is diff. (whereas Chalmers would argue there are possible worlds where all physical facts are the same but facts about consciousness are diff.)

Comment: It should be noted that this definition of 'strong emergence' isn't universal - many would consider this to actually be 'weak emergence' -- `We can say that a high-level phenomenon is strongly emergent with respect to a low-level domain when the high-level phenomenon arises from the low-level domain, but truths concerning that phenomenon are not deducible even in principle from truths in the low-level domain.`